# spring boot unix service is not picking up mode option

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am having an spring boot app with 2.0.2.RELEASE and trying to run as unix service. The jar is inside bin folder. The bin folder also has a .conf file with the same name as jar.  But when I run the jar with the command ./app-name.jar  , it is run as foreground process and not as background process.

The .conf file has MODE=service. The jar seems to be picking up only the JAVA_OPTS from .conf file and nothing else.

Did i miss anything ?

Comment: Which linux distro?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, I install my spring-boot microservice as a service on linux:

Build as an executable spring-boot:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>build-info</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  <plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

Create a systemd service file

```
[Unit]
Description=My Boot Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myfolder/myboot/
ExecStart=/opt/myfolder/myboot/target/mybooter.jar
User=booter
Group=booter

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service

```
Copy / soft link your jar to /etc/systemd/system (or maybe /lib/systemd/system)
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable my_service.service
sudo systemctl start my_service.service
```

Now it should start as a service when you reboot. Logs are in journalctl -u mybooter -f -n 500